# How to get names containing particular Character in Java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a workbook in which I have multiple tabs now I want to read all the tabs name and return the tab name containing particular character in it , in my case its data
example assumpition is :-

Expected tabsname  - > welcome_data.xslx , hello_value.xslx;

output -> welcome_data.xslx

Any help is appreciated ,

code which I was trying was :- I was able to get the tabs name but how to filter it .

```
import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
    
    public class EXcelsheet {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String xlsxFile = "/home/working/git/ui_spec.xlsx";
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(xlsxFile));
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            System.out.println("number of sheet::" + workbook.getNumberOfSheets());
            List<String> sheetNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
                sheetNames.add(workbook.getSheetName(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the issue.

Does replacing

```
sheetNames.add(workbook.getSheetName(i));
```

with

```
String sheetName = workbook.getSheetName(i);
if (sheetName.contains(<char>)
{
    sheetNames.add(workbook.getSheetName(i));
}
```

not work?